# if else with $_GET not working

Tags: php

What I am trying to do is echo out  based on the $_GET['page'] variable however its echoing this out for all of my navigation menu's.  How can I only have it use the page I am on?  This is only the php part of it, the actual html code goes below each line however for simplicity I did not include it

```
<?php if($_GET['page'] == 'user_edit' || 'NULL'){ echo "<li class=\"current\">"; } else{ echo "<li>";} ?>
<?php if($_GET['page'] == 'manage' || 'add' || 'ftp'){ echo "<li class=\"current\">"; } else{ echo "<li>";} ?>
<?php if($_GET['page'] == 'bugs' || 'support' || 'notifications'){ echo "<li class=\"current\">"; } else{ echo "<li>";} ?>
```

Comment: Why do you have an echo for `<li>` in the `else` part of the if-statements.

Comment: The syntax you are using is incorrect.  Please [review the PHP language reference](http://php.net/langref), in particular the area on [control structures, like `if`](http://php.net/language.control-structures) and [logic operators like `||`](http://php.net/language.operators.logical).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work like this. Your conditions are evaluated as:

```
if ( ( $var == 'foo' ) || ( 'bar' ) || ( 'baz' ) )
```

Note the grouping above. All three are separate expressions. It does not mean "if `$var` equals 'foo', 'bar' or 'baz'", it means "if `$var` equals 'foo' is true or 'bar' is true or 'baz' is true".

And `'bar'` is always `true`.

You need:

```
if ($var == 'foo' || $var == 'bar' || $var == 'baz')
```

or

```
if (in_array($var, array('foo', 'bar', 'baz'))
```

Comment: D'oh, beat me by 4 secs. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is no good:

```
if ($_GET['page'] == 'manage' || 'add')
```

In this case, the string 'add' evaluates as boolean true, which means the condition will fire every time. You want this instead:

```
if ($_GET['page'] == 'manage' || $_GET['page'] == 'add')
```

Or this:

```
if (in_array($_GET['page'], array('manage', 'add')))
```